# Select top distinct results ordered by frequency

Tags: sql, mysql, count, distinct

My table has two columns: id and name. The data looks like this:

```
id | name
----------
1    Jeff
2    Sam
3    Carl
4    Sam
5    Carl
6    Jeff
7    Dave
8    Jeff
```

What I want to obtain is this:

```
name | frequency
----------------
Jeff      3
Carl      2
Sam       2
Dave      1
```

Essentially, I need an SQL query that counts the unique names within the table, and sorts them by their frequnecy. I'm using MySQL if it matters.

Thank-you.

Answer (score 37):

I haven't tested it, so the syntax might not be perfect, but what about something like this :

```
select name, count(*) as frequency
from your_table
group by name
order by count(*) desc
```

Should give you unique names and the corresponding number of times each name appears in the table, ordered by that number.

Comment: Just a little addition order clause may be like "order by frequency desc" as well

Answer (score 19):

You need to use a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as frequency
FROM name_table
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

This will `GROUP BY` `name` (any non-aggregate columns needs to be named in the `GROUP BY` clause) and then `COUNT` the frequency of each `name`.

If you want only the top 25, you can then proceed to add a `LIMIT` clause as such:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as frequency
FROM name_table
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

More information about the `GROUP BY` clause is available in the MySQL Manual:

> [12.2.8 SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Thank you, Andrew. Very nice of you.