# ordering results by frequency in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am new to Rails and Active Record queries. I want to order my query results by frequency.

As an SQL query it be:

```
SELECT author FROM books GROUP BY author ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

(Which I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217244/select-top-distinct-results-ordered-by-frequency) and was very helpful in framing this question.)

What I have right now will do it alphabetically:

```
<p>The authors are: <% @books.select(:author).distinct.order(:author).each do |book| %>
  <br><%= book.author %> <%= @books.where(author: book.author).count %>
<% end %></p>
```

Which will get me, e.g.:

> Asimov, Isaac 2
>
> Dick, Philip K. 8
>
> Pynchon, Thomas 3

etc. 
But I want to order the results by frequency (Dick, Pynchon, Asimov), not alphabetically.

I want to leave the author name and number of books as separate outputs if possible (want to be able to switch it to a table), although I'm sure there's a better way of getting the frequency in the output (instead of `@books.where(author: book.author).count` ), too. But the main issue is getting the initial ordering right.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Book.group("author").order("count_author desc").count("author")
```

So your view will look like

```
<% @books.group("author").order("count_author desc").count("author").each do |author, count| %>
  <br><%= author %> <%= count %>
<% end %></p>
```

Comment: Just FYI: queries should be in the controller

Answer (score 2):

Using the sample query below and the generated sql

```
Task.group(:project_id).limit(10).count(:id)
SELECT COUNT(`tasks`.`id`) AS count_id, project_id AS project_id FROM `tasks` GROUP BY project_id LIMIT 10
Output: {18=>1206, 22=>82, 23=>25, 25=>77, 29=>1, 35=>1, 42=>30, 44=>1, 45=>17, 53=>12}
```

You can see that by convention, rails uses `count_<column name>` for the count.  You can use this convention to order by that count.

```
Task.group(:project_id).limit(10).order('count_id DESC').count(:id)
SELECT COUNT(`tasks`.`id`) AS count_id, project_id AS project_id FROM `tasks` GROUP BY project_id ORDER BY count_id DESC LIMIT 10
Output: {145=>1949, 105=>1535, 18=>1206, 141=>738, 23804=>667, 9892=>524, 196=>478, 26969=>338, 24119=>330, 28047=>300}
```

A better way to do what you want to achieve is to prepare the variables in the controller and access them in the view

```
# controller
@counts = Book.group(:author).order('count_id DESC').count(:id)

# view
<% @counts.each do |author, count| %>
  <%= author %> <%= count %>
<% end %>
```

`@counts` above contains a hash where the keys are the author, and the values are the counts of the books by that author.