# Way to execute this in one query

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks something like this

```
Table: Recommendations
Recommended_ID    Item_ID     Recommended_Item_ID    User_id
1                   1                   3                1
2                   1                   3                6
3                   1                   2                7
4                   2                   5                1
```

And I want my SQL query to achieve something like this in pseudocode:

```
SELECT recommended_item_id as f, COUNT(recommended_id) WHERE recommended_item_id = f AND item_id = 1, FROM `Recommendations` WHERE item_id = 1

To hopefully return:
Recommended_Item_ID   Recommended_Number_of_Times
3                              2
2                              1
```

Basically, I'm trying to get all the item ids that were recommended for item_idx and return how many times they were recommended as well as their ID. How can I get my SQL query to do this? I've tried GROUP BY and HAVING, but the problem is I don't know how to ensure that the recommended_item_id is equal to the initial_recommended_id I told SQL to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217244/select-top-distinct-results-ordered-by-frequency) and [where and group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073497/can-we-use-group-by-and-where-condition-with-same-fieldname).

Try *group by*

```
select Recommended_Item_ID, count(*) as Recommended_Number_of_Times
from Recommendations
where Item_ID = X
group by Recommended_Item_ID
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  Recommended_Item_ID,
  COUNT(recommended_id)
from `Recommendations`
where Item_ID = 1
group by Recommended_Item_ID
```

Comment: I rolled back my edit as it did not accurately reflect what you were suggesting, but .. it would be helpful to others if you added a brief explanation of how the above solves the issue :)